# Yocto project building: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found

Tags: yocto

I need to build an image using `Yocto project` with custom layers and device tree to work on Oclea hardware.
I'm on `Ubuntu 20` with `ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.14) 2.31`

I've seen that the filesystem NTFS might be the issue but I'm on `ext3/ext4`.

Here is the full output when running the build:

```
./example-build.sh --platform s5l
You had no conf/local.conf file. This configuration file has therefore been
created for you from /media/data/Data/Oclea_project/oclea-yocto-sdk-3.0.0-rc1/oclea-yocto-sdk/poky/meta-poky/conf/local.conf.sample
You may wish to edit it to, for example, select a different MACHINE (target
hardware). See conf/local.conf for more information as common configuration
options are commented.

You had no conf/bblayers.conf file. This configuration file has therefore been
created for you from /media/data/Data/Oclea_project/oclea-yocto-sdk-3.0.0-rc1/oclea-yocto-sdk/poky/meta-poky/conf/bblayers.conf.sample
To add additional metadata layers into your configuration please add entries
to conf/bblayers.conf.

The Yocto Project has extensive documentation about OE including a reference
manual which can be found at:
    https://docs.yoctoproject.org

For more information about OpenEmbedded see the website:
    https://www.openembedded.org/


### Shell environment set up for builds. ###

You can now run 'bitbake <target>'

Common targets are:
    core-image-minimal
    core-image-full-cmdline
    core-image-sato
    core-image-weston
    meta-toolchain
    meta-ide-support

You can also run generated qemu images with a command like 'runqemu qemux86'

Other commonly useful commands are:
 - 'devtool' and 'recipetool' handle common recipe tasks
 - 'bitbake-layers' handles common layer tasks
 - 'oe-pkgdata-util' handles common target package tasks
Adding bitbake layers
NOTE: Starting bitbake server...
Loading cache: 100% |                                                                                                                                     | ETA:  --:--:--
Loaded 0 entries from dependency cache.
Parsing recipes: 100% |####################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:09
Parsing of 2657 .bb files complete (0 cached, 2657 parsed). 4107 targets, 361 skipped, 0 masked, 0 errors.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies
NOTE: Multiple providers are available for runtime libgstcodecparsers-1.0 (gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad, gstreamer1.0-plugins-base, gstreamer1.0-plugins-good, gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly, gstreamer1.0-rtsp-server)
Consider defining a PREFERRED_RPROVIDER entry to match libgstcodecparsers-1.0
NOTE: Multiple providers are available for runtime libgstvideo-1.0 (gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad, gstreamer1.0-plugins-base, gstreamer1.0-plugins-good, gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly, gstreamer1.0-rtsp-server)
Consider defining a PREFERRED_RPROVIDER entry to match libgstvideo-1.0

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "2.0.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "ubuntu-20.04"
TARGET_SYS           = "aarch64-oclea-linux"
MACHINE              = "oclea-s5l"
DISTRO               = "oclea"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "1.0"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "aarch64 armv8a crc cortexa53"
TARGET_FPU           = ""
meta                 
meta-poky            
meta-yocto-bsp       = "HEAD:1861941037c4cca6fdfa3154f65d82ea96ab761f"
meta-oe              
meta-python          
meta-networking      
meta-multimedia      
meta-filesystems     
meta-webserver       = "HEAD:5f120a926b0fcd55cfe7565bb7ddf23661cad498"
meta-oclea-open      
meta-oclea-prebuilt  
meta-oclea-source    
meta-oclea-distro    = "HEAD:1861941037c4cca6fdfa3154f65d82ea96ab761f"

WARNING: Unable to get checksum for oclea-log SRC_URI entry oe-logs: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/media/data/Data/Oclea_project/oclea-yocto-sdk-3.0.0-rc1/oclea-yocto-sdk/poky/meta-oclea-open/recipes-core/oclea-log/src/oe-logs'
WARNING: Unable to get checksum for oclea-log SRC_URI entry oe-workdir: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/media/data/Data/Oclea_project/oclea-yocto-sdk-3.0.0-rc1/oclea-yocto-sdk/poky/meta-oclea-open/recipes-core/oclea-log/src/oe-workdir'
Initialising tasks: 100% |#################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:01
Sstate summary: Wanted 2139 Local 2135 Mirrors 0 Missed 4 Current 0 (99% match, 0% complete)
NOTE: Executing Tasks
NOTE: oclea-log: compiling from external source tree /media/data/Data/Oclea_project/oclea-yocto-sdk-3.0.0-rc1/oclea-yocto-sdk/poky/meta-oclea-open/recipes-core/oclea-log/src/
WARNING: oclea-image-3.0.0-rc1 do_rootfs: QA Issue: The license listed BSD was not in the licenses collected for recipe cyw-supplicant [license-file-missing]
WARNING: oclea-image-3.0.0-rc1 do_rootfs: QA Issue: The license listed BSD was not in the licenses collected for recipe murata-binaries [license-file-missing]
ERROR: ota-7z-3.0.0-rc1 do_assemble_7z: ExecutionError('/media/data/Data/Oclea_project/oclea-yocto-sdk-3.0.0-rc1/oclea-yocto-sdk/poky/build/tmp/work/oclea_s5l-oclea-linux/ota-7z/3.0.0-rc1/temp/run.do_assemble_7z.291416', 1, None, None)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /media/data/Data/Oclea_project/oclea-yocto-sdk-3.0.0-rc1/oclea-yocto-sdk/poky/build/tmp/work/oclea_s5l-oclea-linux/ota-7z/3.0.0-rc1/temp/log.do_assemble_7z.291416
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_assemble_7z
| Device-trees      oclea_s5l_micro_som.dts     oclea_s5l_janus.dts     oclea_s5l_evk2.dts     oclea_s5l_breakout_evk_hydra.dts
| /media/data/Data/Oclea_project/oclea-yocto-sdk-3.0.0-rc1/oclea-yocto-sdk/poky/build/tmp/work/oclea_s5l-oclea-linux/ota-7z/3.0.0-rc1/host-tools/dtc: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /media/data/Data/Oclea_project/oclea-yocto-sdk-3.0.0-rc1/oclea-yocto-sdk/poky/build/tmp/work/oclea_s5l-oclea-linux/ota-7z/3.0.0-rc1/host-tools/dtc)
| /media/data/Data/Oclea_project/oclea-yocto-sdk-3.0.0-rc1/oclea-yocto-sdk/poky/build/tmp/work/oclea_s5l-oclea-linux/ota-7z/3.0.0-rc1/host-tools/dtc: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /media/data/Data/Oclea_project/oclea-yocto-sdk-3.0.0-rc1/oclea-yocto-sdk/poky/build/tmp/work/oclea_s5l-oclea-linux/ota-7z/3.0.0-rc1/host-tools/dtc)
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
ERROR: Task (/media/data/Data/Oclea_project/oclea-yocto-sdk-3.0.0-rc1/oclea-yocto-sdk/poky/meta-oclea-distro/recipes-bsp/ota-7z/ota-7z.bb:do_assemble_7z) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 5031 tasks of which 5004 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
```

Comment: You can probably check this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/1408049/how-can-i-get-glibc-2-35-on-ubuntu-20-04 or even build your Yocto build with a 22.04 Ubuntu version in container.

Comment: @admstg that is terrible advice; Don't update your libc isolatedly, that will inevitably cause headache.

Comment: Yes I don't want to do that. I'll try it only on a VM that I'm installing now

Comment: I tried compiling and installing glibc from source and I get segmented fault when I run some commands line like ls, source, etc

Comment: I created a VM with Ubuntu 20.04 and I faced the same problem. I decided to upgrade to Ubuntu 21 with GLIBC 2.34 and I successfully built with yocto project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a VM with Ubuntu 20.04 and I faced the same problem. Then, I decided to upgrade to Ubuntu 21 with GLIBC 2.34 and I successfully built the image using Yocto project.